# One-To-Many Relationship Django

Tags: python, django, one-to-many

I am coding up a dictionary using Django.
I want a word to have multiple definitions, if necessary.
This would be a one-to-many relationship, but Django does not seem to have a `OneToManyField`.

This is a snippet of my code:

```
class Definition(models.Model):
    definition = models.CharField(max_length=64)

class Word(models.Model):
    word = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True)
    definitions = models.ForeignKey(Definition, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="word")
```

I would like to do `word.definitions` and get back all the definitions of that word.
Also, deleting a word should delete all definitions of that word. Finally, `a_definition.word` should give me the word associated with that definition.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use `ForeignKey` in `Definition` class. `Definition` will have relation to `Word`:

```
from django.db import models

class Definition(models.Model):
    definition = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    word = models.ForeignKey(Word, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Word(models.Model):
    word = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True)
```

And you can query it likes this:

```
from .models import Word, Definition

word = Word.objects.get(word = 'test')   #get Word object
definitions = Definition.objects.filter(word = word)   #get all Definition objects related to word object above

for definition in definitions:   #print all definitions related to word
    print('%s -> %s' % (word.word, definition.definition))
```

Comment: Is there any use for a related_name field option for cases like this?

Comment: @FredPercudani I found this answer on reddit, which seems useful: https://www.reddit.com/r/django/comments/76a7uw/related_name_in_modelspy/ As I understand, you can call `word.definition_set.all()` to get all definitions by given word object but I don't see big advange in changing `related_name` to something different.